# Definir Limite de Gastos por Grupo de Recursos

Tags: microsoft-azure

É possível definir limies de gastos dentro de uma assinatura do Azure por Grupos de Recursos?

Ex.:

1. Assinatura 1 - 500 USD

   - Grupo de Recurso 1 - 100 USD
   - Grupo de Recurso 2 - 400 USD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NAO**, não é possível limites os gastos de um grupo de recursos. Ao menos não via configuração do RG, seja portal ou PS.

Existe a maneira de se criar uma assinatura pré paga, nessa vc terá sim limites de gastos por período, mas para ter uma assinatura dessa, é necessário a pré compra de um bom volume de créditos - algo próximo de USD 12K/ano - não é certo isso, necessário verificar.

**MAS**,  é possível desenvolver algo para ajudar nisso. Uma combinação de Azure Functions + Azure PowerShell deve fazer o serviço.